# .Bat File, File Copy/Instal

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, copying

Im making a mod pack for a game, and the install seems to confuse people for some reason, and basicly all it is, is move 1 folder, @ACMP, to a set location that should be the same for everyone, except for on x86 or 32 bit PC's (e.g. `C:/Program Files(x86)`)

What i need is a simple .bat program to move the files in the folder that the program is in, to that certain location.

The file dir's:

The Mod Pack is going to be in a zip, they extract the zip. 
Inside the pack folder is 2 things: `Install.Bat` & @ACMP(folder) 
The program takes @ACMP, and moves it too:
`c:/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/Arma 3/`
OR
`c:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/SteamApps/common/Arma 3/`

So if this can be done, i would be very thankful, And if there is way to see if the pc's running x86 or 32 bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In future you need to show some evidence of having attempted to figure out the problem before asking how to do it.

Something like this should pretty much do it.

```
@echo off

set installdir=Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 3\

if exist "%ProgramFiles%\%installdir%" (
    set installdir=%ProgramFiles%\%installdir%
) else (
    if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\%installdir%" (
        set installdir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\%installdir%"
    ) else (
        echo Could not find install directory & pause & goto :EOF
    )
)


echo %installdir%
copy "@ACMP" "%installdir%"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i apologize for not showing my work, i was messing with xcopy for awhile, but those variables i did not know how to do. Thanks again mate!

Comment: No problem. You will tend to get downvoted to shit if it's not obvious that you've at least tried something. Hit accept for this answer if it's working for you.

Comment: it did not work, i even edited it to bare bones without "%", to tell it what mine says, it always pops up cannot find install

Comment: Try wrapping the path in the `if exist` statements in quotation marks. `if exist `%ProgramFiles%\%installdir%"`. It's probably because of any spaces in the directory name.

Comment: I tried your wrapping, and your new code. the new code ended up quickly flashing and closing, i managed to get a screen shot of what it says, looks like a extra "/" in there. http://i.imgur.com/eRCxaBM.jpg

Comment: Just a tip - run the batch file from a command prompt, that way the output will stay on the screen. Think about where the error is coming from. The `installdir` variable is set as `\Steam...`, I've later used it by checking `%ProgramFiles%\%installdir%`, I've already included the `"\"` in the variable. Simply remove the leading `\` when setting the `installdir` variable - I will edit my answer.

Comment: I'm not actually testing this myself, all the pieces are there - see if you can figure out what's wrong.